# How can I save the current form if browser crashes or it's closing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following form for a Questionnaire application.

http://contoso2.azurewebsites.net/Test/ExamPreview?content=RTEsNXxEMCw1fFEw

The thing which I'm dealing know is if the user accidentally closes its browser, the web should recover the same data which the user established until he finishes it's questionnaire.

I was trying to use OutputCache but I supposed I'm not in the right way. What could you recommend me to store all that user data?

Answer (score 0):

As the user enters data, store it in an object.  When the browser closes, you can then do whatever you want with the data in your object.  Presumably, you would write it to a db and wait until that user came around again, pre-populating the form with the data from your object.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to tie into the blur event of all the input elements. Using JQuery:

```
$(input).blur(function(){});
```

Inside the function you could save the data using Web Storage (if browser supports HTML5), Cookies or Post to the server using Ajax. You can also use a library like Modernizr to help you detect the browser capabilities.

Links: 
Blur event: http://api.jquery.com/blur/

HTML5 web storage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp